# Camlink 4K blank screen on MacBook Pro

Tags: catalina, webcam

I am trying to use CamLink 4K, connected to a well-configured 2018 MacBook Pro (running Catalina 10.15.7, 19H15) with Apple’s [USB-A to USB-C adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MJ1M2AM/A/usb-c-to-usb-adapter), with mixed results. I am finding that the CamLink 4K starts out working fine, but sometimes goes blank/black as I continue to use the Mac. When this happens, my other two webcams (the “FaceTime HD Camera” built-in the MacBook Pro and the “LG UltraFine Camera” built in my external monitor) continue to work fine. Only the CamLink 4K goes dead. The CamLink 4K is still listed as a video source, but no video is being delivered. I am using it connected to a Sony a7Rii, but have the same problem with a7Riv.

Reading this Reddit post, [How I finally got my Cam Link 4K to work reliably w Macbook Pro](https://www.reddit.com/r/ElgatoGaming/comments/ch3mzv/how_i_finally_got_my_cam_link_4k_to_work_reliably/), it looks like I'm not the only user to struggle with this, and the conclusion there is not terribly satisfactory. I am trying their counsel to not have other USB devices connected in the nearby port, which seems to delay how quickly the CamLink gives out on me (but it eventually does). Sometimes disconnecting and reconnecting seems to fix it. Sometimes I seem to have to resort to a reboot.

All I am trying to do is to get a good, reliable connection to use my Sony cameras as quality webcams (and the [Sony Imaging Edge Webcam](https://www.dpreview.com/news/6130831741/sony-brings-its-imaging-edge-webcam-utility-to-macos-updates-windows-version) is definitely a version 1.0 implementation and does not work, either).

If anyone if familiar with this sort of problem, that would be

Comment: FWIW, the HD60 S+ works flawlessly. It's just a problem with the CamLink 4K.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is coming really late, but I ran into the same problem and found an easy solve. It seems that the problem comes from the camlink + Sony combo requiring more power than the computer wants to supply through its USB 3.0 port (max of 900 mA), so I used a powered USB 3.0 hub that way I am not relying on my Mac to power the Cam Link.

Here's the cheap powered hub i got at walmart.
https://www.walmart.com/ip/onn-AC-Powered-USB-3-0-Hub-with-4-USB-Ports/325592700

Comment: Having bought a fancy powered hub, while it initially it looked like the Camlink 4K was working, after a few hours, it died on me again. I've gone back to the HD60 S+. 